# Notation Linear Algebra, Kostrikin's book

Tags: notation

What does the Kostrikin's book mean when writes:

Let $f: M \to N$ a linear transformation and $\{e_i\}$, $\{e_k'\}$ basis of $M, N$ vectors spaces, respectively.

Then, he defines: $f(e_1,\ldots, e_n) = (f(e_1),\ldots,f(e_n))=(e_1',\ldots,e_m')A_f.$

What it supposes to mean? How to interpret this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the two bases.

Comment: yeah, this is what I thought, but, which are the advantages of this?